# How do I set the foreignKey column when bulk creating instances of a model with Sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a one to many relationship between my Polls model and Options model, where one Poll can have multiple options.

The association is set so that Options has a pollId column, which needs to have the correct id from the poll model inserted.

```
var Options = sequelize.define('Options', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING, 
      allowNull: false
    },
    votes: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Options.belongsTo(models.Polls, {
          foreignKey: 'pollId', 
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

I am using bulk create to create multiple options at once, like so

```
models.Users.findOne({
        where: {uuid: user_id}
    }).then((user) => {
        models.Polls.create({
            createdBy: user.get('name'),
            userId: user_id, 
            voter_ids: []
        }).then((poll) => {
            models.Options.bulkCreate({

            })
        })
    });
```

Not sure how to add the pollId option to each entry to reflect the same poll model instance, in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `bulkCreate()` you have to manually add the pollId to the options. Which you could easily do: `{pollId: poll.id}`

But theres an even better option:
You can issue a single `create()` including the poll and the options. Simply add the options to the poll and specify that you want to create these too using the `include` option of `create()` See: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-elements-of-a-hasmany-or-belongstomany-association

```
models.Polls.create({
    createdBy: user.get('name'),
    userId: user_id, 
    voter_ids: [],
    options: [
      {your first option},
      {another option}
    ]
  }, {
    include: [ models.Options ]
  }
)
```